# can't understand why I'm getting maximum recursion depth here

Tags: python, sorting, recursion

I have such function:

```
def sort(lst, beg, end):
    mid = (beg + end)/2
    sort(lst, beg, mid)
    sort(lst, mid, end)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for l in range(beg, end):
        if j > end - mid or (i <= mid - beg and lst[beg + i] < lst[mid + j]):
            lst[l] = lst[beg + i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            lst[l] = lst[mid + j]
            j = j + 1
```

Input is : sort([1,5,6,6,3,1,5,4,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,5,3,2,4,5], 1, 10)

as output:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Implement a base case check for when end <= beg

Answer (score 5):

You are missing a condition that will stop you from recursing. In the current implementation, you will just continue indefinitely.

e.g.:

```
def sort(lst, beg, end):
    if end - beg <= 1:
        return

    mid = (beg + end)/2
    sort(lst, beg, mid)
    sort(lst, mid, end)
    # rest of code
```

Comment: @Smith It is because you are not returning the list in that 'sort' function. You are changing/moving the list items directly. Can you print your list after you call the 'sort' function?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing preventing the recursion. Every time sort is called, it will call itself 2 times. There should be a conditional statement.